# Alternative To Microsoft Source Safe / TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Myself and my girlfriend house a large amount of files on our computers and we are soon looking to get a shared desktop. I suggested to her that we version control all files on an external drive / server to ensure that we can always roll back versions if we make a change we are unhappy with (although in reality, us using the same files would be rare).

I have been playing on and off with subversion for a little while. At work, we generally use Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (which I have heard some very strong opinions of) whilst at home I have been having a play with Tortoise SVN.

My biggest issue with Tortoise SVN is when checking in a document, the working folder is still treated like an active repository resulting in the need to delete the svn directory before you can once again check out to the folder.

Overall, I have not been completely happy with my experience with Tortoise SVN (sadly) and was wondering if you could all advise. I am ideally looking for something very similar to SourceSafe where all files can be maintained through a visual interface for checking out / checking in and a singular working folder can be set and checked out to / checked in from an infinite number of times.

Oh, and I would *ideally* like it to be free, but it's not a deal breaker.

Comment: *>  large amount of files*
What kind of files? Maybe Skydrive / Dropbox will do better than a full-fledged version-control such as SVN? Do you really need to track any change? Do you need immutable revisions? Do you need log messages for your changes?

Comment: 1/ Don't misuse **any** VCS - you want to have *reliable backup system*, not SCM. 2/ Using SCM for storing binary artifacts is The Bad Idea (tm)

Comment: I guess I was kind of convoluting the whole scenario. The files that I would be using could be anything from from C# .CS files to Photoshop PSDs. I would like the ability to track change, not necessarily to replace the act of backing up files but just to make sure that if I need to roll back, I don't have to create a full backup to ensure that I have that copy, I can just roll back comfortably.

Comment: That’s a weird description of what’s going on with Subversion. You’re not perchance trying to have your working copy and your repo be the same folder, are you?